# WooCommerce Subscriptions count renewal orders and add to column

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

We are using WooCommerce Subscription and want to add a new column in the subscription overview page (/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=shop_subscription).

We want to count all already paid renewal orders and then out put that in a column next to end date.

This is what we have so far. But it does not work

```
function count_paid_renewals( $subscription ) {

    $get_paid_count = $subscription->get_payment_count( 'renewal' );

    foreach ( $subscription->get_items() as $item ) {

            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php esc_html_e( 'Count: ' . $item->get_product()->get_title(), 'woocommerce-subscriptions' ); ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo esc_html( $get_paid_count ); ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
    }

add_action( 'woocommerce_subscription_before_actions', 'count_paid_renewals', 99, 1 );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will add the admin columns, and retrieve the subscription payment counts for each type and combine.

```
function dd_columns_head( $defaults ) {
    // add the count column after end date.
    return array_slice( $defaults, 0, 10, true ) +
        array( 'count' => 'Count' ) +
        array_slice( $defaults, 10, count( $defaults ) - 1, true );
}
function dd_column_content( $column_name, $post_ID ) {
    if ( 'count' === $column_name ) {
        $subscription = wcs_get_subscription( $post_ID );
        if ( is_a( $subscription, 'WC_Subscription' ) ) {
            // Here your subscription details are in the $subscription variable.
            $completed_count = $subscription->get_payment_count( 'completed', 'renewal' );
            $pending_count   = $subscription->get_payment_count( 'pending', 'renewal' );
            echo '<table>';
            foreach ( $subscription->get_items() as $item ) {

                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php esc_html_e( 'Count: ' . $item->get_product()->get_title(), 'woocommerce-subscriptions' ); ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo absint( $completed_count + $pending_count ); ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
            echo '</table>';

        }
    }
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_subscription_columns', 'dd_columns_head', 30 );
add_action( 'manage_shop_subscription_posts_custom_column', 'dd_column_content', 30, 2 );
```

Comment: yes thanks. But the count is wrong. it displays always 0 :(

Comment: If you just change it to `$get_paid_count = $subscription->get_payment_count` what do you end up with?

Comment: Then is also counts the parent subscription order. I only want to count the renewal orders.

Comment: I've updated the answer... Try `$get_paid_count = $subscription->get_payment_count( 'completed', 'renewal' );`

Comment: Thanks, but now it reflects the same as before. We want to count all renewal orders and not just those whicha re completed. So also them in processing state. But adding 'processing' does not work.

Comment: If you check the manual, the first param must be string.  https://woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/functions/#section-17 so you have to get individually and add.  I've updated the answer again.